# Equivalent of VLOOKUP in C#

Tags: c#, vlookup

Ive been struggling to figure out what the correct way to do this is.
I have a table in Excel that relates Motor horsepower size to the amount of space it takes up.

[image]

I would like to implement a lookup function of this information in a C# Windows Form that I am writing.
**I want to create a function that has a single argument passed to it (double HP). It would lookup if the motor HP falls in-between "Low" and "High" and then it would return the value in the "Space Factor" column.** I feel pretty silly for not knowing the best way to do this. I want to avoid IF/Else statements as it doesnt seem like the right approach. Additionally, interfacing with Excel to do the lookup also seems a little silly.

**How would you interface with a data table like this?**

Comment: You want to create a C# class to model your data. A property for "Nema", "HP Low", "HP High", "Space Factor", etc. Then import your data into a container of some sort (List, Array, etc) in your program using the class you just created. Now you have the ability to filter the data source. (~ `data.Where(x => x.HpLow > value).Select(x => x.SpaceFactor) ...` )

Comment: There are various ways depending on how your table data's stored.  Most options will implement some form of [where](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) method though which you could call with `myData.Where(x => x.High >= searchValue && x.Low <= searchValue)`.  Note: your question's worded as if you'll only get one result; but if your ranges overlap it's possible you may get more (or none); so you should be prepared for those scenarios.

Comment: How did I not know to do a linq where/select? I think I got tripped up because I was trying to avoid manually entering data... Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an class to represent your rows, you can then add each object to a list. If you have few items you can just use Linq:

```
var hp = 20;
var objects = new List<MyClass>(){...};
var foundObj = objects.FirstOrDefault(o => hp > o.HpLow && hp < o.HpHigh);
if(foundObj != null){
   // Found object!
}
```

If you have lots of rows you can instead sort the list by the `HpHigh`, and use [BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-binarysearch(-0-system-collections-generic-icomparer((-0)))) to find the item without iterating over all items, but it requires a custom comparer and is a bit more complex.

If hp-ranges can overlap for you need some way to determine which of the rows is the most fitting one, so I'm just going to assume ranges do not overlap.

Comment: BinarySearch with a comparison on `HpHigh`  is almost certainly the right approach, since it'll close the gaps in a safe direction (not causing overload of the selected option).

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure I'm following, do you suggest a linear search is not appropriate if there is only a few items? Or that it works better if the HP-ranges overlap and multiple items may fulfill the search criteria?

Comment: Choosing a single column to search (and `HpHigh` is likely a better/safer choice than `HpLow`) and finding the upper-bounding element (ala C++ "std::upper_bound") is the correct solution, no matter whether a linear or binary search is employed.  I'm more concerned about the gaps in coverage in the actual data in the question, than about hypothetical overlaps, but searching for upper-bounding element using a single column solves both problems.  Note that a linear search can only stop early if either (a) the list is sorted or (b) the element sought happens to be an exact match.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, but if you have 6 rows, (or a thousand for that matter), any possible performance difference will be irrelevant. And in that case checking both columns at once tend to make the code simpler and easier to read, and I really do not see any issue with gaps if you pick the first item within the range. Sure, you will need to traverse all items if you do not have a match, but for a handful of items it will not matter the least. And if there are millions of rows, a SQL database would probably be more appropriate than excel.

Comment: Lookup `12` in the data provided in the question.  LINQ comparing two columns will fail.  Upper-bounding element over `HpHigh` will succeed, returning the row with `Nema 2`.  Like I said, doesn't matter whether you use linear or binary search for the upper-bounding search implementation.  But you seem fixated on *overlap*, while the actual problem, which is not theoretical because it exists in the example data, is *gaps*.

Comment: @BenVoig If you search for the value 12 using my example, no object will be found, since there are no objects matching the  criteria `12 > o.HpLow && 12 < o.HpHigh`, so `FirstOrDefault` will return null. I really do not understand the problem.

Comment: In contrast, I consider it far more useful to return the `{ Nema = 2, HpLow = 15, HpHigh = 25, SpaceFactor = 1 }` row from the search routine (for an input of `Hp = 12`), and let the caller decide whether to (a) accept the closest match of sufficient capacity or (b) hit the user with a cluestick.

Comment: @BenVoigt But that directly contradicts the specifications: " if the motor HP falls **in-between** "Low" and "High""

Comment: And that in turn contradicts "equivalent of `VLOOKUP`".  If the search doesn't enforce the lower limit, it's easier for the caller to add enforcement with a single check on the value returned from search.  If the search does enforce it, the caller who wants to pick the smallest larger capacity is just out of luck.  Follow the single responsibility principle and have the search only worry about finding the upper-bounding element via `HpHigh`, and not also be responsible for enforcement of `HpLow`.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally do this with c# arrays, however it might not be best or most practical solution for your solution, which im not quite sure how it works, however array is quick and easy to setup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).